# How to use Using block when DbContext has a DbContextOptionsBuilder Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

When I start my application in the Startup.cs file, I have to pass my connection string that is from my appsettings file to my DbContext like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<ManagementStudioDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DatabaseConfiguration:ConnectionString"]));
```

In my ContextFactory class where my DbContext is created, it passes a DbContextOptionsBuilder variable to my DbContext as well like this:

```
public ManagementStudioDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
{
    //Debugger.Launch();
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(ConfigurationManager.GetBasePath(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CENTRAL_APPLICATION_SETTINGS")))
    .AddJsonFile("mssettings.json")
    .Build();
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ManagementStudioDbContext>();
    builder.UseSqlServer(configuration["DatabaseConfiguration:ConnectionString"]);
    return new ManagementStudioDbContext(builder.Options);
}
```

This is how I declared my DbContext:

```
public ManagementStudioDbContext(DbContextOptions<ManagementStudioDbContext> options) : base(options)
{

}
```

However, this is a problem when I want to use the using() block as I will need to pass a parameter of type options to it. What can I pass so that I can use this using() block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you don't. It has *never* been acceptable to use an EF context with `using`, but now with everything being dependency injected, it's flat out untenable. If you need a copy of your context, you need to inject it into the constructor of your class:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly ManagementStudioDbContext _context;

    public Foo(ManagementStudioDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    ...
}
```

The context is scoped, so if you need it in a singleton-type object, you'll have to utilize the service-locator anti-pattern. Inject `IServiceProvider` into your class with a singleton lifetime and then when you need a copy of your context:

```
using (var scope = provider.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ManagementStudioDbContext>();
    // do something with context
}
```

It's called an anti-patten because you should really avoid doing this if at all possible. Generally speaking, objects should not work with objects with more limited lifetimes than themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this true only for .net core apps? I tried it with a windows form app and the using block seemed to work well.

Comment: "Seemed" being the operative word. EF has things like object caching, change tracking, object fixup, etc. that all depend on it being relatively long lived, and when you constantly new it up in different areas, you're going to have all sorts of issues arise from that. It should pretty much always be request scoped. If you didn't run into issues with `using`, that's merely because you got lucky and happened to not use it again in that way during the same request.